# Как посчитать время полученное с сервера с текущим временем в формате HH:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Бекенд присылает время: например 12:24:16(время на компьютере может отличаться, поэтому время приходит с сервера). При нажатии на кнопку save нужно отправить форму и указать текущее время при отправке формы, если мы получили 12:24:16, форму мы заполнили через 5 мин после получения первого времени то я должен отправить 12:29:16. Как это можно реализовать с moment.js или javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем так сложно? Можно ведь при отправке формы на сервере сразу получать время с помощью `date('h:i:s')`.

Если нужно вычислить сколько времени пользователь тратит на заполнение формы, то смотри в сторону [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) или сохраняй время в hidden поле, после чего вычисляй разницу на сервере или просто в БД сохраняй оба значения.

Я считаю нет смысла заниматься постоянными вычислениями, чтобы добиться времени отправки формы, когда ты на сервере это время по факту получаешь.